# AngularJS linking module to data from JSON

Tags: angularjs

So I'm building an application with AngularJS.

I get my data from JSON. The JSON exists from data that has a label, an x coordinate, an y coordinate and a width/height.

I do this with this code in my `controller.js` file:

```
function locationController( $scope, $http, getCss) {
    $http.get('file.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.locations = data;
    });
}
```

And I output it in my HTML like this:

```
<section ng-controller="locationController">
    <ul>
        <div ng-repeat="location in locations" ng-style="location.css()" >
            <p>{{location.label}}</p>
        </div>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Now I want to make a service that generates the CSS for the div I'm repeating. It's based on the width/height x en y coordinate of the location I get from JSON.

Here is the code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.factory('getCss', function() {
  return {
    css : function(x , y , value) {
      return {
                backgroundColor: "#333",
                x: (x - value) + 'px',
                y: (y - value) + 'px',
                width: (value * 2) + 'px',
                height: (value * 2) + 'px',
                color: "#FFF"
             }
    }
  }
});
```

But how do I link this service to each location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose the `getCss` service on the controller, like this:

```
function locationController( $scope, $http, getCss) {
  $http.get('file.json').success(function(data) {
   $scope.locations = data;
 });
  $scope.css = function(location) {
   return getCss.css(location.x, location.y, location.value);
  }
}
```

And on the HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="location in locations" ng-style="css(location)" >
    <p>{{location.label}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Really having trouble getting started with angular, doesn't seem to much good info out there on the internet.

Thanks a bunch!